# "Variable not Define" error in JsonConverter when executing in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask for your help regarding on my code, I am trying to convert Excel into Json file and I am having/encountering error variable is not define,Can someone tell me what is missing, may be Reference or missing declaration?

Below is my code:

```
Sub CreateJSONFile()
Dim jsonItems As New Collection
Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary
Dim jsonFileObject As New FileSystemObject
Dim jsonFileExport As TextStream

Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Variant
Dim colNum As Integer

Dim excelRange As Range

Set wsDst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
Set excelRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

colNum = 2
For i = 2 To excelRange.Rows.Count
    If wsDst.Cells(8, colNum) <> "" And wsDst.Cells(7, colNum + 1) = "" Then
        jsonDictionary("Object") = wsDst.Cells(8, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("Xpath") = wsDst.Cells(9, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("height") = wsDst.Cells(10, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("background-color") = wsDst.Cells(11, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("width") = wsDst.Cells(12, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("font-family") = wsDst.Cells(13, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("font-size") = wsDst.Cells(14, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("font-weight") = wsDst.Cells(15, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("font-style") = wsDst.Cells(16, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("font-stretch") = wsDst.Cells(17, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("line-height") = wsDst.Cells(18, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("letter-spacing") = wsDst.Cells(19, colNum)
        jsonDictionary("color") = wsDst.Cells(20, colNum)

        jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary
        Set jsonDictionary = Nothing
    End If
    colNum = colNum + 1
Next i

MsgBox JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3)
Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Cells(1, 2).Value & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Cells(7, 2).Value & ".json", True)
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))

Set wsDst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Wheee is JsonConverter declared and instantiated? If it hasn’t been instantiated, it’s a nothing object.

Comment: I copied this code from a reference i googled.... I thought it is a built-in variable/function exists to convert excel to json, you mean this must be a function which is missing?

Comment: It is an entire module of code that is missing and likely also a missing reference. The code is from here: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas   and after adding to your project you need to also go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: I am voting to close this under given reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: ok, thank you for your help and response., seems this is an error that can no longer be resolve, so I will try to get another solutions to convert excel into jason instead... thanks again...

Comment: @Toshi this can be resolved, as outlined in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267213/variable-not-define-error-in-jsonconverter-when-executing-in-vba#comment99150509_56267213). You need the module `.bas` file from the link mentioned, as well as a the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: I tried to create a module and copy/paste the code in the link provided but I am getting a syntax error in this line "Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter""

Comment: name the module JsonConverter

Comment: It works now, Thank you very much....

Comment: VB attributes aren't handled by the VBE code panes, you weren't supposed to copy/paste that module, you were supposed to *import* it ;-)